# What does Emphasize mean?

Tags: meaning

For instance the exclamation mark is used for emphasis but what is emphasis exactly?

I have read that it means special importance but what does that mean?

Comment: When you emphasise a word, you draw the reader's attention to it - like **this!**

Comment: @KateBunting is it different from showing emotions and raising voice which are functions of exclamation mark?

Comment: Well, obviously an exclamation mark only exists in writing, but it can represent a surprised tone or a raised voice in speech.

Comment: is "a surprised tone or raised voice in speech" the same thing as emphasis?

Comment: In speech, a word is usually emphasised by raising the voice, or saying it slowly and clearly - which may be indicated in writing by _italics_.

Answer (score 0):

Emphasis is a general term used (as stated in a comment) to give special attention to a word, phrase or sentence.  All natural-languages have mechanisms for emphasis. You should try to imagine how you would answer this question for your native language.

English can give emphasis by stress (saying a word or phrase louder or slower) intonation (the rise and fall of pitch), syntax (changing the order of words), word choice and a range of adjuncts that have an emphatic effect.  (I'm probably missing some methods)

In text, emphasis can be made by syntax and word choice, but as there is no stress or pitch in written English, emphasis can also be indicted by font changes (bold and italic) and punctuation (notably the exclamation mark).

Whatever method is used, emphasis marks some parts of speech as being more important.

The exclamation mark in particular indicates that the sentence expresses a strong emotion (surprise, joy, anger etc) and would be spoken emotionally.  There is no simple recipe here.  I can't say that it means the sentence should be louder, slower or intoned differently.  You need to look at the context and infer the emotional state of the person.

Comment: is emphasis the same thing as showing emotions or changing intonation like raising or lowering voice?

Comment: No.... I feel like you haven't read my answer. Emphasis is *giving special attention to a word, phrase or sentence*  There are many techniques for emphais.  It exists in every natural language.

Comment: for example this sentence "Go away! " in this sentence it shows anger and maybe a raised voice but is it emphasized? I don't think that it is emphasized because where is the special importance?

Comment: What is the context?  You can't talk about something having special importance unless you place it into a context with some other things that were said that have less importance or were not marked. This is an "exclamation" and is therefore marked relative to the other things that were said "'Go away!' he shouted, and then shrugged, 'or don't. I'm tired of arguing with you.'"

Comment: does an exclamation mark always show emphasis or can it show emotions and/or change in voice like raising voice without emphasis?